# SinonJS is failing to resolve "resolve" as a function

Tags: sinon

I have the following code.

```
getCallStub.returns(new Promise((resolve)=>{
    resolve([item]);
}));
```

But there has to be an easier way so I look at the [Sinon docs](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/) and see something like `getCallStub.resolve([item]);` should work but I get...

> TypeError: getCallStub.resolve is not a function

I also tried `getCallStub.usingPromise(Promise).resolve([item]);` and got the same...

> TypeError: getCallStub.usingPromise(...).resolve is not a function

I double checked the node_modules and I am at a version greater than 2 (6.3.5) so why can't I use the resolve function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

```
stub.resolves(value);
```

Seems you just forgot an `s` and your code should be

```
getCallStub.resolves([item]);
```